# WinForms - Disable drag over MenuStrip & other windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made a Windows Forms solution. In the main shell, there is added a MenuStrip, and it's possible to add more Views onto it.

The problem is, that when I add/open a new View, it is opened behind the MenuStrip.
[image]
Somehow, I want the MenuStrip to have a border, so it is not possible to drag things behind it, but I have no idea how.

The same case should be with other Views.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Dock` property for the control that you want to add.

Comment: I have tried to `menuStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Top;`, but does not help. When dragging, it is even possible to drag even the mouse pointer over the MenuStrip.

Comment: set the Dock property for the control that you want to add、not MenuStrip's Dock

Comment: Tried that as well. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I thought it was an easy task to do - but I am new with Winforms.
I have the same thing with other views; I do not want one to be dragged in front of another.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a solution - I don't totally like it but it works! You will need the usual MDI suspects in terms of flags, etc.

The main form that is the MDI container needs to have something like:

```
public partial class MainForm  : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int BodyCount = 0;

    private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MDIChildForm child = new MDIChildForm();
        child.TitleText = String.Format("Child window {0}", ++BodyCount);
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.Show();
    }
    /*
    ** This could be fun - shouldn't recurse!
    */
    public void ShifTheChild(MDIChildForm spoiltBrat)
    {
        var m = menuStrip1.Height;
        if (spoiltBrat.Location.Y < m)
            spoiltBrat.Location = new Point(spoiltBrat.Location.X, 0);
        return;
    }
}
```

The child forms need the location changed event hooking:

```
public partial class MDIChildForm : Form
{
    public String TitleText 
    {
        get { return this.Text; }
        set { this.Text = value; }
    }

    MainForm parent = null;

    public MDIChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ShowIcon = false;
    }


    private void MDIChildForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (parent != null)
            parent.ShifTheChild(this);
    }

    private void MDIChildForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
    }
}
```

When you move a child into the twilight zone under the menu it will be snapped back out - the method that moves it will cause the event to fire again but the second time nothing should happen (so no recursion).

I don't like this solution simply because I can't get my brain around whether there is a condition that **would** make it recurse, and I don't like uncertainty.

Good luck.